# Why am I getting error Permission denied @ rb_sysopen when my computer trys to run bundle install

Tags: ruby, terminal, permissions, bundle

I am trying to install Metasploit and one of the steps is to run the bundle install command. I am doing this on terminal on mac osx. But when ever I try to do this, this happens:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
/Users/soldenh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/cache/metasploit-payloads-1.2.6.gem
An error occurred while installing metasploit-payloads (1.2.6), and
Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install metasploit-payloads -v '1.2.6'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

When I run a ./msfconsole it says:

> Your bundle is locked to activesupport (4.2.7.1), but that version
>   could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If
>   you haven't changed sources, that means the author of activesupport
>   (4.2.7.1) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a
>   different version of activesupport (4.2.7.1) that hasn't been removed
>   in order to install.

How do I fix this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it suggested, run

```
gem install metasploit-payloads -v '1.2.6'
```

Comment: That doesnt do anything!

Comment: seems you've changed rails or active support gem version in `Gemfile`, you can either run `bundle update` or change them back